# Is there a JSR 257 ("Contactless Communication API") C API available?

Tags: c, api, jsr257

I am trying to implement [JSR 257](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=257) ("Contactless Communication API") API and required to use C programming language. I am wondering if anyone knows of similar C API available so one can use as a basis. What would be a best approach to do this? I am thinking of going ahead and starting to design/implement one but do not want to re-invent if something similar exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSR 257 seems to be about various forms of "short range" communication, wireless. The examples of technologies given are [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification), [near field communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_Field_Communication), and [barcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode).

- [This page](http://www.rfidguardian.org/index.php/General_RFID_Links#Open-Source_Projects) lists various open source RFID implementations.
- Near field communication is a rather new field, I was not able to find any existing APIs doing a quick search. My suggestion is to look at hardware vendors that make ICs supporting it, and searching from there. One such vendor seems to be [NXP](http://www.nxp.com/#/pip/pip=[pfp=50326]|pp=[t=pfp,i=50326]).
- [Zebra Crossing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is a Java library for interpreting barcodes. It's not C as you requested, but it might be of interest anyway. There's talk of (so far only partial) C++ ports on the homepage, those might be of interest too.

Comment: thanks unwind for the information. I am actually working on NFC and we have already demonstrated it's functionality on a phone. I now want to provided applications a way to use this functionality hence the need for an API that is similar to already existing APIs.